OpenCV displays black windows for multiple USB camera streams using multithreading
I'm working on a project that involves streaming from a few USB cameras simultaneously using Python and OpenCV. I've been experimenting with multithreading to handle both camera streams concurrently, but I'm encountering an issue where the imshow function only displays blank black windows for both cameras.
My code, simplified:

import cv2
import concurrent.futures
import time

def gen(src):
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(src)  
    if not vid.isOpened():
        print(f"Error reading camera {src}")
        return

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        flag, frame = vid.read()
        if not flag:
            print(f"Failed to capture frame from camera {src}")
            break
        cv2.imshow(f"Camera {src}", frame)
        cv2.moveWindow(f"Camera {src}", src*300, 0)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == ord('q'):
            break

    vid.release()  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    try:    
        executor.map(gen, (0, 2))
    except Exception as e: 
        print(f"Error executing thread function: {e}")    



The windows for both cameras display as black, even though the cameras are correctly connected and functioning when tested individually.
Changing cv2.VideoCapture(src) to cv2.VideoCapture(2) or cv2.VideoCapture(0) works, so cameras work individually in the code.
I adjusted time.sleep duration to see if it would make a difference. Nothing
Thanks in advance!
Also, crediting this older post for syntax help:
how to run multiple camera in threading using python

you can't run GUI across multiple threads. all GUI toolkits hate you for trying that, some handle it more gracefully. all the GUI calls have to come from a single thread, and for some GUI toolkits it has to be the main thread, the one you didn't spawn.

Ah, I understand. What about reading frames in separate threads and collecting them from the main thread into the imshow window?

that should work fine. having that in a thread might also work fine. you can use multiple windows even in that case. you just need to send your frames into a queue, perhaps as a tuple (index, frame), and then dish them out to the right window in your main loop. -- waitKey does the event processing. it's not really about getting keys. that belongs in the main loop, which would be the event loop.

if my comments solved your issue, let me know, so that I can post an answer. the answer someone provided below is flawed.

Make sure to handle all eventualities though. :)

That solves it, feel free to post an answer, Christoph Rackwitz.

Because I only have one camera I had to test like this:
import cv2

sources = [
    0,
    'https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4'
]

capture_list = [cv2.VideoCapture(i) for i in sources]
frames_list = [None for i in sources]

while True:

    for i, c in enumerate(capture_list):
        _, frames_list[i] = c.read()
        cv2.imshow(f'Window: {sources[i]}', frames_list[i])

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


for capture_item in capture_list:
    capture_item.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Instead of actual parallel processing, creating threads, using multiprocessing or else, we just write the frames into a list and take them from a list to display them. If it's only about displaying n streams, this should be working.

you haven't used any threading there. I think that's not an answer to the question. further, your "solution" synchronously reads frames from all sources. if the sources happen to have even slightly deviating rates, that WILL cause issues. involving a list is pointless. I think this is a junk answer. I'll have to pay attention to you some more.

You could substitute the list for a queue and be done. This is just a PoC how to display multiple streams at once. It wasn't specified that threading needs to be used.

no, that won't help either. OP used threading, likely because of this issue. if you don't use threading, at least you shouldn't introduce such a flaw. if you post on the OpenCV tag, you should post decent answers.

It's not a flaw, I posted a PoC with all parts intentionally written the way they are. Yes OP tried threading, OP didn't say threading is needed, OP only said that they needed to display multiple src at once.

it may be a PoC but it has the flaws I pointed out. as such, anyone reading your answer should be made aware of this. you removed the threading. that causes further issues that cannot be ignored.

I literally wrote in my answer that it is not parallel. Not sure what you're on about.

that would explain why the flaw is there. you must have missed what I said. I'll repeat. you're reading the cameras/sources synchronously, i.e. one frame from each of them. if any of them has even a slightly different frame rate, which happens in practice, then the slowest of them will determine the pace, and the faster ones will queue up frames until the driver throws an error. when you're trying to answer advanced questions like those on the OpenCV tag, you need to be aware of more than python programming.

Yes, thank you, but I am well aware. That's why I only wrote a PoC and not a Solution. Do you expect me to handle all possible cases?

Threading was the point so I would increase speed and avoid lagging, as this is all practice for a bigger project I have, sorry for the misunderstanding.
